# Aref (from Hungarian babel) in bookdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

In the Hungarian language the definite article depends on the word that comes after the article (it can be either `a` or `az`). To account for this, the Hungarian - magyar - Babel ([magyar.ldf](http://www.math.bme.hu/latex/lakk/texmf/tex/generic/magyar/magyar.ldf)) introduces the `aref` (and some related commands) in lieu of the usual `ref`. E.g. `\aref{fig:1}. ábra` compiles to `az 1. ábra`, but `\aref{fig:2}. ábra` becomes `a 2. ábra`. (See the [LaTeX Companion](https://books.google.hu/books?id=iX9MAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA563#v=onepage&q&f=false) as well.)

Is it possible to achieve this with `bookdown`? Unfortunately - but unsurprisingly - no `\@aref()` seems to exist there.

Comment: Have you tried `\aref` without the `@`?  Generally in Markdown pure LaTex is passed through.  Of course, if you are targetting HTML output, this wouldn't work.

Comment: @user2554330 Thanks for the idea, it works (but changing to `aref` is not enough, of course you also have to replace `()` with `{}`) but unfortunately I also need non-LaTeX output. (That's why `\@ref()` is nice because it works for both.)

Comment: @user2554330 Thank you very much! The LaTeX seems to work perfectly, but the HTML doesn't: it outputs `a 1.1.` instead of `az 1.1.`. The reason seems to be that `magyar_article` checks whether the number's length is divisible with 3, if it begins with 1. That makes perfect sense for numbers, but not for labels, because `1.1` is pronounced the same as `1`, i.e. everything that comes after the first period is irrelevant from the pronunciation aspect (and thus from the article aspect). Also there is another thing, but that is surely just a typo: `ar` should be `az`. Thank you again!

Comment: @user2554330 Sure! I just did it, thank you again. (It'd be nice, if this would be eventually included in `bookdown`...!)